# Did Jamshid Piruz enter the UK unchallenged?

Tags: united-kingdom, law-enforcement

From the Daily Mail, but also mentioned by Russia Today and similar sources: [link](https://www.google.com.au/amp/www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4089016/amp/Why-wasn-t-foreign-killer-turned-away-UK-border-Afghan-beheaded-Dutch-woman-allowed-Britain-assaulted-Gatwick-staff-member-two-police-hammer.html)

> Afghan-born Jamshid Piruz was allowed to enter the UK unchallenged despite being sentenced to 12 years in jail for slaughtering his female tenant in cold-blood after watching a Taliban beheading video.
>
> Fury erupted after it emerged that the jobless 34-year-old was the latest in a string of foreign criminals to commit horrific offences in Britain after exploiting EU free movement rules.
>
> MPs condemned the shocking lack of checks on offenders from the EU which left gaping holes in UK border controls.
>
> European countries have no obligation to alert the UK about convictions of murderers or sex offenders, meaning many are able to travel to the UK unhindered.

Was Jamsid Piruz able to enter the UK with no impedences or extra scrutiny resulting from his past murder?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm then you might want to adjust the phrasing of your last sentence.

Comment: @Federico how does it look now?

Comment: imho, this way it is better.